# mocha tests not running with grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mocha.js

The test runner appears to be running from the output, but the test I've written isn't running.

Here's my [gruntfile](https://gist.github.com/jtmkrueger/9102183), and this is the test I'm hoping to see run

```
/*global describe, beforeEach, assert, it  */
'use strict';

describe('Main View', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        this.Main = new fleetDna.Views.MainView();
    });

    test('should have a render() method', function () {
        expect(typeof this.Main.render).to.equal('function');
    });
});
```

the output in the watch log reads `>> 0 passed! (0.00s)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `describe->it->test`? ie. `describe(... it(... test(...)))`

Comment: @Xotic750 it doesn't run even if I include it.

Comment: Well, that's the way that I understand that it should be. Here is an example https://github.com/Xotic750/util-x/blob/master/tests/arrayLast.js although I am using `expect` rather than `test` (don't know what `test` you are using, there are many out there) And the docs demonstrate the same http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/

Comment: @Xotic750 still not the issue. even if I change `test` to `it`, nothing gets run.

Comment: No, `test` should b contained within `it`

Comment: Based on the exchange between you and @Xotic750 I see that the tests are not to blame(?). Your `Gruntfile.js` is relatively long... That's not necessarily bad but the longer it is the more can go wrong. Have you tried commenting out/disabling parts of it to debug?

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée yes, but thus far to no success.

Answer (score 0):

```
var expect = require('expect');

describe('Main View', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        ...
    });

    it('should have a render() method', function () {
        expect(typeof this.Main.render).to.equal('function');
    });
});
```

Comment: like I said, this doesn't change anything

Comment: Have you `required` the necessary `expect` or `assert` or whatever you are using, like in my example?

Comment: yes, still doesn't work. I tried copying this word for word (obviously adding my beforeEach code) and it doesn't get picked up.

Comment: And how are you calling `mocha`? Something like `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --check-leaks -u bdd -t 10000 -b -R tap tests/*.js`?

Comment: I'm using yeoman with [generator-backbone](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) to do all that.

Comment: Well, all I can say, with the information that you have presently given, is that if your test files are structured correctly as shown, then that is not the problem and so you need to look elsewhere for clues.

Comment: Even if I insert jibberish into the test, I can't get it to throw an error. I agree, the test file is not the issue. I think it's something in the gruntfile.

Comment: I took a quick look at your `Gruntfile` but did not notice anything wrong. I don't know anything about the `yeoman` stuff, so I don't think I can be much more help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've misplaced your tests. In which directory did you put them? The script expects them to be somewhere in test/spec or a subdirectory of that.

Update: adding --verbose to your grunt command might give some extra helpful feedback.